# How to update mountpoint of an existing process in a different namespace

Tags: linux

Suppose an init process reads from fstab to establish an initial mountpoint list in some namespace. It spawned two child process tree A and B with cloned mountpoints.

Suppose also that I have a root shell created under tree B, how can I update the mount point of an existing process in tree A?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. That's what the different namespaces are meant to do. Separate the process into an area that has no effect on the old process' mount points.

Of course, by "you can't", I don't necessarily mean you absolutely can't. There are tricks that can work, but I'm not sure that's what you mean. You can write a kernel module that can do anything. You can use ptrace to manipulate the other process into doing the mount command as well.

All in all, it sounds like you want the two processes to share a mount namespace, which causes me to wonder why you decided to create a new namespace to begin with.